# Residuals for cumulative penalized ordinal models with ordinalNet in R

Tags: r, statistics, statmodels

I'm using the [ordinalNet](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ordinalNet/versions/2.7) package in R for a cumulative elastic model.
I want use surrogate residuals for the diagnostics. 
The package [sure](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sure/) doesn't work with ordinalNet models.
Someone knows others packages to get residuals for ordinalNet or can you help me in another way?

Comment: I found a quick solution in the use of generalized residuals. Take a look here: "Quantitative Models in Marketing Research" by Philip Hans Franses and Richard Paap. section 6.3.1